# Can i save byteArray to mp3 file?

Tags: actionscript-3

Well, i am recording the voice from heaphone and the sound data is stored in ByteArray at runtime, now can i stored as mp3 ??
i want to save as mp3 file on the client system.. For that, i think i have to use air application.. Am i right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this [link](http://blog.debit.nl/2009/03/mp3-encoder-in-flash-with-alchemy/) where someone used [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/) to convert to MP3.